# Complex SQL query with ACF relationship

Tags: sql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to make a complex SQL query but without a success.

I have 2 CPT, 'release', 'track'.
Release has 1 taxonomy 'artist', and 1 ACF multiselect 'tracks' connected with 'track' cpt.
Track has 2 ACF multiselct 'singers' and 'composers' connected with 'artist' terms.
I have 1 Taxonomy, 'artist' which is connected to 'release' only.

If i search a term in Query 'ArtistName', it should query all artists with a name like that.
Then find if these artists ids are used in ACF fields (singers, composers) at 'Track' CPT.
Use these matched tracks ids to find every 'release' that includes it in 'tracks' ACF.
Then filter out any 'release' that these artists ids are selected in taxonomy 'artist'.

To recap, query release ids where artist ids are used only on 'track' ACF fields but not main 'release' taxonomy 'artist'.

My attempt:

```
function get_releases_by_artist_search_term( $search, $page = 1, $per_page = 10 ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $offset = ( $page - 1 ) * $per_page;
    $query = $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT DISTINCT r.ID
        FROM {$wpdb->posts} r
        JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} t ON r.ID = t.post_id AND t.meta_key = 'tracks'
        JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} ta ON r.ID = ta.post_id AND ta.meta_key = 'artist'
        JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} atr ON r.ID = atr.object_id AND atr.term_taxonomy_id = ta.meta_value AND atr.term_taxonomy_id IN (
            SELECT term_id FROM {$wpdb->terms} WHERE name LIKE %s
        )
        JOIN {$wpdb->posts} tr ON t.meta_value = tr.ID AND tr.post_type = 'track'
        JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} s ON tr.ID = s.post_id AND s.meta_key IN ('singers', 'composers)
        JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} at ON s.meta_value = at.object_id AND at.term_taxonomy_id = ta.meta_value
        WHERE r.post_type = 'release' AND (ta.meta_value NOT IN (
            SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships} WHERE object_id = r.ID AND taxonomy = 'artist' AND term_taxonomy_id IN (
                SELECT term_id FROM {$wpdb->terms} WHERE name LIKE %s
            )
        ) OR ta.meta_value IS NULL)
        LIMIT %d OFFSET %d",
        '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $search ) . '%',
        '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $search ) . '%',
        $per_page,
        $offset
    );
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );

    return wp_list_pluck( $results, 'ID' );
}
```

Comment: Please add your current attempt to question too.

Comment: Just added my attempt

Comment: What is the failure? No rows in your result set? Some kind of syntax error? What's the text of the actual query? (you can get it from [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/).Please [edit] your question to explain more completely.

Comment: Please update your question, using editable text, to show sample data and the result you are trying to achieve